# WordPress Custom Theme: If I allow excerpts to link to an external URL should I use no-follow?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type which has excerpts showing on a page. If I program the ability for the continue link to link an external URL, should I have a no-follow in my page meta for that post since the post will be empty of content?

Answer (score 0):

> **rel="nofollow"**.
> Use the nofollow value when other values don't apply,
> and you'd rather Google not associate your site with, or crawl the
> linked page from, your site. (For links within your own site, use
> robots.txt, as described below.).
>
> Links marked with these rel attributes will generally not be followed.
> Remember that the linked pages may be found through other means, such
> as sitemaps or links from other sites, and thus they may still be
> crawled. These rel attributes are used only in  tags (because
> Google can follow only links pointed to by an  tag), except
> nofollow, which is also available as robots meta tag.

*Source @ https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/qualify-outbound-links?hl=en*

If you can control the content or trust the content at the end of the link, you don't need to add `rel="nofollow"`. A case where you would want to use `rel="nofollow"` would be links from comments on a website.